# Sending M.Sc. dissertation to a big conference

Tags: thesis, conference, paper-submission

I am a very recent Ph.D. student (since October 2014), and the deadline date of the conference in which I want to participate is quite near.  I don't want to miss the conference, but as I am so new in my Ph.D. program, I don't have something really concrete for the moment.  For this conference, however, it is possible to revise the paper until 15 days before the conference.

Accordingly, I am thinking of submitting my M.Sc. dissertation to the conference. As I think I will have an improved version of my M.Sc. in 3-4 months (at least, I really hope), I suppose that it is worth doing this.

Is it really a bad idea to submit a M.Sc. dissertation to a conference? Are there some ethical issues to consider?

Comment: I did a grammatical cleanup; please revert anything that I got wrong with respect to your original intent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically a dissertation is not considered to be a peer reviewed publication.  This means that the material in it can be extracted and turned into conference or journal publications.  In some fields, this is a typical practice after completing a dissertation, where in others it goes the other way (the dissertation is assembled from peer-reviewed papers).

You cannot, however, just submit your thesis directly as is.  A dissertation is generally much longer than conference or journal papers.  A dissertation typically also has much more freedom in style, and does not have to be targeted at the biases of a particular community.  Thus, to make a credible conference submission, you will need to compress or extract a nugget of contribution of an appropriate size, and may also need to tailor its focus and language to better match that of the conference where it is being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what [jakebeal](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/22733/jakebeal) says in [his answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/36577/14017) about ways to make a submission based on your Master thesis, and I would like to add that you could talk to your former Master thesis supervisor. Maybe he or she is interested in drafting a submission together with you. As your supervisor, they are probably more or less interested in the topic.

*For example, everyone supervising a graduation thesis in my own department is always strongly encouraged to create at least one paper out of that thesis, and while mostly, students are not interested in writing anything themselves and we only present refactored parts of what they created (which ultimately means that their effective contribution warrants co-authorship among the less significant positions), we are always entirely happy and supporting if a student actually wants to become one of the main authors and writes parts of the paper him- or herself.*

Like this, you could benefit from writing together with someone more experienced who can help you create a submission that has a certain chance of being accepted.

(All of the above is under the assumption that your Master thesis topic is somehow related to your PhD research, so both are somewhat compatible with the conference in question.)

Furthermore, I would like to respond to the following statement you make:

> I don't want to miss the conference

This sounds like your primary objective is to attend the conference. That is a legitimate desire, for reasons such as getting a good overview over the state of the art in your field, getting some first external contacts in your field, or simply for learning how conferences in your field look and feel in general.

You may want to talk to your supervisor exactly about that wish, as there may be various options:

- If your department's finances allow for that, you might be allowed to attend without presenting anything. At my own department, new doctoral candidates are often allowed to attend one conference in the very beginning of their career even if they do not have any submission, just to learn how conferences work (preferrably, that is a conference that is attended by at least one other member of the department, so they also have someone to "show them around").
- Even though you have nothing "really concrete for the moment", if you have started looking into some things, defined something on an abstract level that you are about to try, or have a certain plan, you could think about preparing a minor submission to the conference, e.g. a poster or a workshop paper. On this type of papers, it is often acceptable to present work in progress, as one of the main goals is to discuss and possibly refine an approach or model.
- If your work is not concrete enough for that, maybe you could participate in a doctoral colloquium, which is an event somewhat similar to a workshop that is frequently integrated into conferences, as well. Such events are sometimes meant for doctoral candidates to present and discuss their ideas and plans for their upcoming research.